# What's the number of 8-digit numbers satisfying the conditions below?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> The number of $8$ digit numbers divisible by $9$ made from the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ without repetition can be expressed as $a×b!$ such that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Find $a+b$.

I am a beginner at combinatorics. Recently I found this problem. After trying I found the answer $\boxed{883}$. But my friend suggests that the answer would be $\boxed{43}$. As I am a beginner I'm not sure which is the answer. Please solve this with procedure.

Comment: This really looks like a Project Euler problem (for the way to synthetize the answer). Care to say where it came from ?

Comment: Also, what have you tried ? Why would you find 883 ?

Comment: No, I found it on Facebook @hugo

Comment: See the [wikipedia divisibility article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_3_or_9).  Although $9$ can be in any position, $0$ probably can't be the leftmost digit.

Comment: What did you get for the number of $8$ digit numbers that are acceptable?  Your friend has one of the two answers.